# Developing a RMI application

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to develop a simple database application, I wish to use RMI technology for this. What I need to know is, are there any common frameworks for developing RMI applications or do we have to develop the server and clients from beginning?

Comment: Do you have to use RMI? ...we have replaced ours with Thrift and found that it works much better in terms of robustness (does not depend on external dependencies), no registry to start, less code, better backwards compatibility, simple and quick learning curve, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at the: [Remoting and web services using Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html). And [there](http://cosminaru.ro/blog/2006/11/02/spring-by-examples-rmi/) you have simple example of this approach.